# Regarding Admiral electric dryer model # ADE7000AYW / Glide Pads & Drum Seals

Tags: repair, dryer

OK the REAL problem, knowing how to fix the dryer & being able to afford ALL of the parts are 2 very different things. The parts aren't as expensive as say the motor, yet I can only afford the Glides & Pads OR the Drum Felt Seal. & Now I'm wondering if the Felt Drum seals, & the Pads, found under the plastic glides, are basically the same material? I'm thinking of replacing the front felt drum seal. Then using the discarded old felt seal to replace the Glide Pads. Will that be a SAFE way to repair both issues? The drum belt is new, but the front of the drum is loudly scraping, top of dryer frame is way too hot, leaving rub marks on the drum. If the felt won't work for the pads, the likeliest part to stop the scraping is Glides&Pads OR the Front Drum Seal?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I doubt you will get a good answer on this, as we'd have to figure out the properties and requirements for the various materials. That said, pictures of the two locations could help.

Comment: What sort of condition are the old parts in?